# plotly graph as margin figure using Tufte style in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, r-plotly, ggplotly, tufte

I am trying to add a plotly graph to the margin of a Tufte handout document using Rmarkdown. The original graph (`h <- ggplot()...` ) was created using `ggplot2` and then converted to plotly by, `ph <- ggplotly(h)`.

When I include the original ggplot chart to Tufte document, it works fine but I lose the dynamic features of plotly charts.

````
```{r margin1, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap = "Number of countries per survey gap", fig.margin = TRUE}
h
```
````

[image: margin_working]

Yet, when I used the plotly chart `ph` it looks now like this,

````
```{r margin1, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap = "Number of countries per survey gap", fig.margin = TRUE}
ph
```
````

[image]

As you can see, the image has now an interactive tooltip, but it is in the body of the text rather than in the margin. However, notice that the caption of the graph is in the margin rather than below the chart, so it seems to be working partially.

How can I move the plotly chart to the margin?

Thank you,